# Animating max-height with CSS transitions

Tags: css, css-transitions, css-animations

I want to create an expand/collapse animation that's powered only by classnames (javascript is used to toggle the classnames).

I'm giving one class `max-height: 4em; overflow: hidden;`

and the other `max-height: 255em;` (I also tried the value `none`, which didn't animate at all)

this to animate: `transition: max-height 0.50s ease-in-out;`

I used CSS transitions to switch between them, but the browser seems to be animating all those extra `em`'s, so it creates a delay in the collapse effect.

Is there a way of doing it (in the same spirit - with css classnames) that doesn't have that side-effect (I can put a lower pixel count, but that obviously has drawbacks, since it might cut off legit text - that's the reason for the big value, so it doesn't cut off legit long text, only ridiculously long ones)

See the jsFiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/wCzHV/1/ (click on the text container)

Comment: Not perfect solution: http://jsfiddle.net/wCzHV/2/ Is this acceptable?

Comment: @Passerby - it might be possible with negative margin, but your example doesn't seem to support having arbitrary height or exposing a preset number of lines (both these things are supported in the original and are essential)

Comment: That's why I don't post that as an answer. This question has somewhat been asked on SO, and I would say that it's almost impossible to achieve in pure CSS (if you don't want to hard-code some value). If you really really need to do that, involve JS.

Comment: I was worried that it might not be possible, that's too bad, I hate to see it almost working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case anyone is reading this, I have not found a solution and went with an expand-only effect (which was achieved by moving the `transition` style to the expanded class definition)

Comment: would you mind posting the solution in a JS Fiddle or similar?

Comment: It's 2016 and it still doesn't have a solution. It's a shame.

Answer (score 134):

Fix delay solution:

Put cubic-bezier(0, 1, 0, 1) transition function for element.

### scss

```
.text {
  overflow: hidden;
  max-height: 0;
  transition: max-height 0.5s cubic-bezier(0, 1, 0, 1);

  &.full {
    max-height: 1000px;
    transition: max-height 1s ease-in-out;
  }
}
```

### css

```
.text {
  overflow: hidden;
  max-height: 0;
  transition: max-height 0.5s cubic-bezier(0, 1, 0, 1);
}

.text.full {
  max-height: 1000px;
  transition: max-height 1s ease-in-out;
}
```

Comment: Best way to do it pure-css. Thanks for the reminder, lost that curve a while ago.

Comment: Could someone explain what does `&.full` mean in this context?

Comment: @Jakub ''&.full" refers to the final state of the text class, so when it has reached its full size

Comment: @Jakub `&.full` is saying - "When the class `.full` gets added to an element with the class `.text`, update the CSS as follows..." Its basically the SCSS way of doing this `.text.full {}`, which is how it would look in normal CSS. It's called nesting and is a feature of Sass/SCSS.

Comment: @Sam thanks, shouldn't it be closed with another curly bracket at the end?

Comment: @Jakub yes it should be.

Comment: This answer desperately needs an explanation. It's upvoted quite a bit, but it doesn't seem to work properly. The only effect I'm seeing, is that the retracting transition is only 0.5s vs the expanding transition that's 1s.

Comment: After looking into it more, I can say with some certainty that this is not a fix, it's a workaround, and it's not even a good one. The only things happening are basically the shorter duration of the animation, and the fact that the function being used is basically an extreme `ease-out`. So basically, you're just contracting those 1000px of max height really quickly, and slowing down in the end, so the final bit looks somewhat like a regular `ease-in-out`. Again: not a fix, but a workaround, and not a good one.

Comment: While implementing this, I found it wasn't working with `max-height: auto`. Is there a specific reason for it ?

Comment: @SalimShamim transition works only with numeric values as for (max-min)height and (max-min)width

Answer (score 12):

This is an old question but I just worked out a way to do it and wanted to stick it somewhere so I know where to find it should I need it again :o)

So I needed an accordion with clickable "sectionHeading" divs that reveal/hide corresponding "sectionContent" divs. The section content divs have variable heights, which creates a problem as you can't animate height to 100%. I've seen other answers suggesting animating max-height instead but this means sometimes you get delays when the max-height you use is larger than the actual height.

The idea is to use jQuery on load to find and explicitly set the heights of the "sectionContent" divs. Then add a css class 'noHeight' to each a click handler to toggle it:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.sectionContent').each(function() {
        var h = $(this).height();
        $(this).height(h).addClass('noHeight');
    });
    $('.sectionHeader').click(function() {
        $(this).next('.sectionContent').toggleClass('noHeight');
    });
});
```

For completeness, the relevant css classes:

```
.sectionContent {
    overflow: hidden;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in;
    -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in;
}
.noHeight {
        height: 0px !important;
}
```

Now the height transitions work without any delays.

Comment: Works like a charm, though I did notice that the height doesn't update properly if the window is resized enough to squeeze elements below the overflow-hidden container. To get around this I put the accordian contents in another div without overflow-hidden, set that div's height on page load, and then put a resize handler on the page that makes sure the accordian's height always matches the inner div. Works beautifully!

Comment: From what I can tell, this solution only works when the content has a fixed height (100px/100em/etc) but no animation will occur if content has height auto, unset, 100%, or anything like that

Answer (score 6):

There is a new pure CSS solution that solves all the issues that other CSS  solutions had. You can use `grid-template-rows: 0fr;` for collapsed and `1fr;` for expanded. Look at the code for details:

```css
/* theme */

.panel-expand {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  padding: 20px;
  width: 400px;
  transition: all 200ms ease-in-out;
}


/* mechanism */

.panel-expand {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 0fr;
}

.panel-expand:hover {
    grid-template-rows: 1fr;
}

.panel-expand__content {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="panel-expand">
  <div class="panel-expand__content">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Modi corrupti, sint distinctio deserunt vel unde consequatur sequi nobis necessitatibus quis ad officiis doloremque ab, blanditiis facere possimus obcaecati voluptate sed!</p>
    <p>Voluptas, ipsa porro? Ex nostrum culpa magnam magni officiis laboriosam fugit molestias amet reiciendis sunt facere, debitis odit neque totam natus ad aliquam minus, sed repellat eveniet, et impedit ipsa.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

I found it mentioned in Kevin Powell video
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=B_n4YONte5A

Comment: This is fine if the height of the grid itself doesn't change, but if you need to expand the grid obviously it won't work.

Comment: Nice ! That is very usefull.

Answer (score 1):

The solution is actually quite simple. Make a child div, that has the content. The parent div will be the one that expands collapses.

On load the parent div will have a max-height. when toggling, you can check the child height by writing `document.querySelector('.expand-collapse-inner').clientHeight;` and set the maxheight with javascript.

In your CSS, you will have this

```
.parent {
transition: max-height 250ms;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use **display:flex**. This will work:

```
.parent > div {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 0px;
  max-height: 0px;
  opacity: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: all 0.3s;
}

.parent > div.active {
  opacity: 1; 
  height: 100%;
  max-height: none; /* important for animation */
}
```

Comment: did not work for me

Comment: Me neither. It doesn't seem to transition at all, just snap.

Comment: it works only for paddings of the active element.

Answer (score -3):

You can accomplish this just fine using [jQuery Transit](http://ricostacruz.com/jquery.transit/):

```
$(function () {
    $(".paragraph").click(function () {
        var expanded = $(this).is(".expanded");
        if (expanded) 
        {
            $(this).transition({ 'max-height': '4em', overflow: 'hidden' }, 500, 'in', function () {$(this).removeClass("expanded"); });
        } 
        else 
        {
            $(this).transition({ 'max-height': $(this).get(0).scrollHeight, overflow: ''}, 500, 'out', function () { $(this).addClass("expanded"); });
        }
    });
});
```

You can definitely tidy it up a bit to your liking, but that should do what you want.

### [JS Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/TheGAFF/aQrER/)

Comment: thanks, I know of ways to do it with javascript, I wanted a way to do it by only changing the classname