# CSS ease-in ease-out not working for max-height 0 and max-height auto

Tags: jquery, css, css-transitions

I am trying to apply an ease in and ease out on one of my wordpress pages like so:

```
.section1 {
    max-height: 0px;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: max-height 0.15s ease-out;
}

.section1.show {
    max-height: auto;
    overflow: visible;
    transition: max-height 0.25s ease-in;
}
```

However this is not working, its not ease-in and ease-out....what am I doing wrong?

I adjusted my code like so:

```
.vc_section {
    max-height: 0px;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: max-height 1.15s ease-out !important;
}

.section1.show {
    max-height: 500px;
    overflow: visible;
    transition: max-height 1.25s ease-in !important;
}
```

The ease-in is working, the ease-out is not. I am trying to get the ease-out to work when the user clicks a button:

```
$('.architectural-films').bind('click', function(){
            if ($(".section1").hasClass("show")) {
                $('.section1').removeClass('show');
            }
            else
            {
                $('.section1').addClass('show');
            }
            return false;
        });
```

Comment: Would you be able to send the html code as well please? Also, would you like it to show on hover?

Comment: How is the class `show` being applied to `section1`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16028878/animating-max-height-with-css-transitions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, `auto` values can not be animated through plain CSS.

You might want to [read this CSSTricks article](https://css-tricks.com/using-css-transitions-auto-dimensions/) for some workarounds.

I would recommend using jQuery's `slideDown()` with the easing you want :)

Answer (score 0):

It's working fine but you won't see the effect you need due to the big value of `max-height`. Basically the `ease-in` will have an effect around the value of `500px` but if your content is having a small height, you will not see this.

Here is a basic example to better understand:

```css
.box {
  background:red;
  height:20px;
  width:100px;
  display:inline-block;
  vertical-align:top;
}


/*your code*/
.box {
    max-height: 0px;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: max-height 1.15s ease-out !important;
}

html:hover .box {
    max-height: 100px;
    overflow: visible;
    transition: max-height 1.25s ease-in !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">

</div>

<div class="box" style="height:100px;">

</div>
```

As you can see, the ease is working fine for the second because its height is big enough to be able to see the effect unlike the first one.

To avoid this, you need to use a smaller value for `max-height` (close to the value of height) or use jQuery to set this value manually and match the element height.