# JQuery Hover Toggle Issue When Page Loads

Tags: jquery

```
$("#menu-main li").hover(function(){
    $(this).find(".sub-menu").animate({
        height: "toggle",
        opacity: "toggle"
    }, "fast");
});
```

I am using this to toggle a menu on hover.

My issue is that if the mouse is over the #main-menu li when the page loads, the toggle becomes backwards because it toggles on when the mouse leave and off when hovered back again.

code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#menu-main li").hover(function(){
        $(this).find(".sub-menu").animate({
            height: "toggle",
            opacity: "toggle"
        }, "fast");
    });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="menu-main">
  <li><a href="#">Home</a>
    <ul class="sub-menu" style="display: none;">
      <li><a href="#">News</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">News</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">News</a></li> 
      <li><a href="#">News</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

I can recreate on here by pressing 'Run code snippet' and quickly hovering  where the 'Home' li will load.

Comment: Please provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) including the necessary CSS and HTML. It will make things easier for those trying to help you and increase your chances of quickly getting a solution to your problem.

Comment: provide complete code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would avoid using JavaScript (and especially adding the overhead of a library) for something like this altogether, to avoid such problems in the first place. So here's a CSS-only solution:

```css
#menu-main .sub-menu {
  overflow: hidden;
  max-height: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: max-height 500ms cubic-bezier(0, 1, 0, 1), opacity 500ms;
}

#menu-main>li:hover .sub-menu {
  max-height: 100vh;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: max-height 1000ms ease-in-out, opacity 500ms;
}
```

```html
Hover menu items to show submenus:
<ul id="menu-main">
  <li>Foo
    <ul class="sub-menu">
      <li>Lorem</li>
      <li>Ipsum</li>
      <li>Dolor</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>Bar
    <ul class="sub-menu">
      <li>Lorem</li>
      <li>Ipsum</li>
      <li>Dolor</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>Baz
    <ul class="sub-menu">
      <li>Lorem</li>
      <li>Ipsum</li>
      <li>Dolor</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Animation delay fix taken from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16028878/animating-max-height-with-css-transitions/18636883#answer-39103740).

Comment: This is brilliant thank you. I was under the impression you couldn't use css to slide toggle without knowing the absolute height. But your solution solves this!