# Height transition with CSS instead of Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have made these cards with HTML and CSS. For height transition, I have used javascript but depends on the page sometimes it works really slow. Is there a way to write this animate function in CSS without my javascript code?
2. Question
I set from 110px to 160px height raisement in JS, is it possible to raise the box's height depends on the text's height so if there is more text hidden the box will raise more?

```js
$('#dynamic-cards .card-box').hover(function(){
   $(this).find('.description').animate({
        'height': '160px'
    }, 500);
},function(){
  $(this).find('.description').animate({
        'height': '110px'
    }, 300);
}).trigger('mouseleave');
```

```css
#dynamic-cards {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  max-width: 1000px;
}
#dynamic-cards .card-box {
  position: relative;
  font-family: Arial, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, sans-serif;
  z-index: 1;
  display: block;
  background: #ffffff;
  height: 450px;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s linear 0s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s linear 0s;
  -ms-transition: all 0.3s linear 0s;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s linear 0s;
  transition: all 0.3s linear 0s;
}

#dynamic-cards .card-box:hover .card-pic img,
#dynamic-cards .hover .card-pic img {
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
  -moz-transform: scale(1.1);
  transform: scale(1.1);
  opacity: 0.6;
}

#dynamic-cards .card-box .card-pic {
  background: #000000;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#dynamic-cards .card-box .card-pic img {
  display: block;
  max-width: 300px;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s linear 0s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s linear 0s;
  -ms-transition: all 0.3s linear 0s;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s linear 0s;
  transition: all 0.3s linear 0s;
}

#dynamic-cards .card-box .card-box-content {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: #EFEFEF;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 15px 15px 0px 15px;
  -webkti-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.37, 0.75, 0.61, 1.05) 0s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.37, 0.75, 0.61, 1.05) 0s;
  -ms-transition: all 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.37, 0.75, 0.61, 1.05) 0s;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.37, 0.75, 0.61, 1.05) 0s;
  transition: all 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.37, 0.75, 0.61, 1.05) 0s;
}

#dynamic-cards .card-box .card-box-content .category {
  position: absolute;
  top: -34px;
  left: 0;
  background: #002776;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 600;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

#dynamic-cards .card-box .card-box-content .title {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0 0 10px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  color: #002776;
  font-size: 26px;
  font-weight: 700;
}

#dynamic-cards .card-box .card-box-content .sub_title {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0 0 20px;
  color: #002776;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 400;
}

#dynamic-cards .card-box .card-box-content .description {
  height: 105px;
  color: black;
  font-size: 15px;
  line-height: 1.4em;
  padding-bottom: 0px !important;
}

#dynamic-cards .card-box .card-box-content .card-box-footer {
  font-size: 14px;
  height: 20%;
  position: relative;
  background-color: #EFEFEF;
  padding-bottom: 27px;
  margin: 0px;
}

#dynamic-cards .card-box .card-box-content .card-box-footer a {
  color: white;
  background-color: #002776;
  padding: 10px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

#dynamic-cards .card-box .card-box-content .card-box-footer a:hover {
  background-color: #009fda;
}

#dynamic-cards .hover .card-box-content .description {
  display: block !important;
  height: auto !important;
  opacity: 1 !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="dynamic-cards">
    <!-- Card-->
    <div class="card-box mb-3">
        <!-- Bild-->
        <div class="card-pic">
            <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/cc/Grey_squirrel_400px.jpg">
        </div>
        <!--  Content-->
        <div class="card-box-content">
            <h2 class="title">Headline</h2>
            <p class="description" style="height: 110px;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed
                diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero
                eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum.</p>
            <div class="card-box-footer">
                <br>
                <a href="htttps://www.hays.de" target="_blank">Button</a>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>

    <!-- Card-->
    <div class="card-box mb-3">
        <!-- Bild-->
        <div class="card-pic">
            <img src="https://blog.tappenbeck.net/wp-content/uploads/2013/07/400px-Smiley_icon.svg_.png">
        </div>
        <!--  Content-->
        <div class="card-box-content">
            <h2 class="title">Headline</h2>
            <p class="description" style="height: 110px;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed
                diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero
                eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
            <div class="card-box-footer">
                <br>
                <a href="https://www.hays.de" target="_blank">Button</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Card-->
    <div class="card-box mb-3">
        <!-- Bild-->
        <div class="card-pic">
            <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/36/Brooks_Range-400px.jpg">
        </div>
        <!--  Content-->
        <div class="card-box-content">
            <h2 class="title">Headline</h2>
            <p class="description" style="height: 110px;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed
                diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero
                eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata.</p>
            <div class="card-box-footer">
                <br>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

https://codepen.io/rahman23/pen/MWweeoN

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16028878/animating-max-height-with-css-transitions

Comment: Why not use the css transform: translateY property

Answer (score 0):

You can create this animation by adding the following style without using JavaScript

```
.card-box:hover .card-box-content{
  transform: translateY(-80px);
}
```

Keep in mind that inserting a static height for text is not a fun job.
I suggest not considering the height and if you have to, consider `overfolow-y:scroll` for it.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by adding transition to your .description class and adding this css code:

```
#dynamic-cards .card-box:hover .card-box-content .description {
    height: 160px;
}
```

For your second question, I myself have searched for it a lot not long ago and found no good answer. If you give height auto to your box it will snap to the 100% height. if you know the max-height of your box you can use max-height other than height itself. Check this article https://css-tricks.com/using-css-transitions-auto-dimensions/

```css
#dynamic-cards {
        display: flex;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        justify-content: space-between;
        max-width: 1000px;
    }
    #dynamic-cards .card-box {
        position: relative;
        font-family: Arial, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, sans-serif;
        z-index: 1;
        display: block;
        background: #ffffff;
        height: 450px;
        -webkit-transition: all 0.3s linear 0s;
        -moz-transition: all 0.3s linear 0s;
        -ms-transition: all 0.3s linear 0s;
        -o-transition: all 0.3s linear 0s;
        transition: all 0.3s linear 0s;
    }

    #dynamic-cards .card-box:hover .card-pic img,
    #dynamic-cards .hover .card-pic img {
        -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
        -moz-transform: scale(1.1);
        transform: scale(1.1);
        opacity: 0.6;
    }

    #dynamic-cards .card-box .card-pic {
        background: #000000;
        overflow: hidden;
    }

    #dynamic-cards .card-box .card-pic img {
        display: block;
        max-width: 300px;
        -webkit-transition: all 0.3s linear 0s;
        -moz-transition: all 0.3s linear 0s;
        -ms-transition: all 0.3s linear 0s;
        -o-transition: all 0.3s linear 0s;
        transition: all 0.3s linear 0s;
    }

    #dynamic-cards .card-box .card-box-content {
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 0;
        background-color: #EFEFEF;
        width: 100%;
        padding: 15px 15px 0px 15px;
        -webkti-box-sizing: border-box;
        -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        -webkit-transition: all 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.37, 0.75, 0.61, 1.05) 0s;
        -moz-transition: all 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.37, 0.75, 0.61, 1.05) 0s;
        -ms-transition: all 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.37, 0.75, 0.61, 1.05) 0s;
        -o-transition: all 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.37, 0.75, 0.61, 1.05) 0s;
        transition: all 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.37, 0.75, 0.61, 1.05) 0s;
    }

    #dynamic-cards .card-box .card-box-content .category {
        position: absolute;
        top: -34px;
        left: 0;
        background: #002776;
        padding: 10px 15px;
        color: #ffffff;
        font-size: 14px;
        font-weight: 600;
        text-transform: uppercase;
    }

    #dynamic-cards .card-box .card-box-content .title {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0 0 10px;
        margin-top: 10px;
        color: #002776;
        font-size: 26px;
        font-weight: 700;
    }

    #dynamic-cards .card-box .card-box-content .sub_title {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0 0 20px;
        color: #002776;
        font-size: 20px;
        font-weight: 400;
    }

    #dynamic-cards .card-box .card-box-content .description {
        height: 105px;
        color: black;
        font-size: 15px;
        line-height: 1.4em;
        padding-bottom: 0px !important;
        transition: all 0.3s linear;
    }

    #dynamic-cards .card-box .card-box-content .card-box-footer {
        font-size: 14px;
        height: 20%;
        position: relative;
        background-color: #EFEFEF;
        padding-bottom: 27px;
        margin: 0px;
    }

    #dynamic-cards .card-box .card-box-content .card-box-footer a {
        color: white;
        background-color: #002776;
        padding: 10px;
        font-weight: bold;
    }

    #dynamic-cards .card-box .card-box-content .card-box-footer a:hover {
        background-color: #009fda;
    }

    #dynamic-cards .hover .card-box-content .description {
        display: block !important;
        height: auto !important;
        opacity: 1 !important;
        transition: all 0.5s linear;
        height: 110px;
    }
    
    #dynamic-cards .card-box:hover .card-box-content .description {
        height: 160px;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div  id="dynamic-cards">
  <!-- Card-->
  <div class="card-box mb-3">
    <!-- Bild-->
    <div class="card-pic">
         <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/cc/Grey_squirrel_400px.jpg">
    </div>
    <!--  Content-->
    <div class="card-box-content">

      <h2 class="title">Headline</h2>

      <p class="description">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum.</p>

       <div class="card-box-footer">
            <br>
            <a href="htttps://www.hays.de" target="_blank">Button</a></div>
       </div>

     </div>

</div>
```