# how do i "fold" a div from the bottom up?

Tags: html, css

i need to hide some information when i check a checkbox, i managed to do it, but it gets folded from the top, leaving the bottom fixed, i am trying to do the opposite, leaving the upper part fixed and folding the div starting from the bottom. can anybody help?

this is the css code:

```
.home.payment.cyber .ade #ignore > div {
  max-height: 340px;
  transition: all .5s linear;
  overflow: hidden;
  opacity: 1;
}

.home.payment.cyber .ade #ignore #ignore_child.fold_transition {
    max-height: 5px;
    transition: all .5s linear;
    opacity: 0;
}
```

Comment: Hi Luisa, can you provide us your html code too

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Animating max-height with CSS transitions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16028878/animating-max-height-with-css-transitions)

Answer (score 0):

Try animating the `margin-top` of the element at the same time as the `height`.

Something like:

```css
div {
  height: 20px;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: .5s;
}

div.toggle {
  height: 0;
  margin-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div onclick="this.classList.toggle('toggle')">Some content</div>
```