# how to apply smooth transition on the element using tailwind css

Tags: next.js, tailwind-css

I have make a nav bar using tailwind css in next.js it is responsive and working fine.

[image: full screen size]

[image: small screen size]
[image: on clicking the burger button]

every thing is working fine but when i click the burger button it shows the list appears instantly but i want to show the bottom (un-order list) on small screen size with smooth transition and i have no idea how to make the transition smooth

- **the solution of the problem i want is to make this list smoothly visible on the screen**

```js
   
    import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";

    import { MenuAlt1Icon } from "@heroicons/react/outline";
    
    function Header() {
      const [isOpen, setisOpen] = React.useState(false);
      const [size, setSize] = useState(0);
    
      function handleClick() {
        setisOpen(!isOpen);
      }
      useEffect(() => {
        setSize(window.innerWidth);
        window.addEventListener("resize", handleSize);
        return () => window.removeEventListener("resize", handleSize);
      }, []);
      const handleSize = () => {
        setSize(window.innerWidth);
      };
```

Above is the javascript code

and below is the jsx and tailwind

```js
    return (
        <header>
          <nav className={` shadow-md  px-5  ${isOpen && size < 640 && "pb-3"}`}>
            <button
              type="button"
              className={`${
                size >= 640 ? "hidden" : "inline-block h-12 focus:outline-none"
              }`}
              onClick={handleClick}
            >
              <MenuAlt1Icon className="h-6 w-6" />
            </button>
    
            <ul
              className={`   ${
                size >= 640
                  ? " flex h-12 items-center space-x-2  "
                  : `${
                      isOpen
                        ? `block space-y-2  border-t-2 border-gray-50 pt-2 transition duration-500 ease-linear`
                        : `hidden`
                    }`
              }`}
            >
              <li>element 1</li>
              <li>element 2</li>
              <li>element 3</li>
              <li>element 4</li>
            </ul>
          </nav>
        </header>
      );
    }
    
    export default Header;
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want a top to down dropdown animation, try to read: [Animating max-height with CSS transitions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16028878/animating-max-height-with-css-transitions)

You can try to use these tailwind classes `transition-all max-h-screen max-h-0`.

Answer (score 3):

Now don't be like me. By applying the class md:hidden to the navbar and hamburger you don't have to check if it clicked again to show the ul or navlinks. What you should instead do is add a negative -translate-x-full to make it display off screen and when the hamburger is clicked add a translate-x-0 to make it show by sliding into the screen. If not the sidebar won't be animated

do this

```
 <ul className={`md:hidden flex flex-col fixed left-0   w-3/4 h-screen top-[60px] bg-green-300 items-center justify-around transition-all ease-in-out duration-200 ${isNavExpanded ? "translate-x-0 " : "-translate-x-full"}`}>
        {links.map((item) => (
          <li key={`link-${item}`} className="nav-link">
            <a href={`#${item}`} className="">
              {item}
            </a>
          </li>
        ))}
      </ul>
```

instead of this

```
{isNavbarExpanded && (<ul className={`md:hidden flex flex-col fixed left-0   w-3/4 h-screen top-[60px] bg-green-300 items-center justify-around transition-all ease-in-out duration-200 ${isNavExpanded ? "translate-x-0 " : "-translate-x-full"}`}>
        {links.map((item) => (
          <li key={`link-${item}`} className="nav-link">
            <a href={`#${item}`} className="">
              {item}
            </a>
          </li>
        ))}
      </ul>)}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

I used Tailwind Responsive Design way in official [Doc](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/responsive-design).

so you can adjust `sm:` or `md:` in the `className`

```
import { useState } from "react";
import { MenuAlt1Icon } from "@heroicons/react/outline";

export default function Header() {
  const [isOpen, setisOpen] = useState(false);

  return (
    <header>
      <nav className={"shadow-md px-5 pb-3 sm:pb-0"}>
        <button
          type="button"
          className={"inline-block h-12 focus:outline-none sm:hidden"}
          onClick={() => setisOpen(!isOpen)}
        >
          <MenuAlt1Icon className="w-6 h-6" />
        </button>
        <ul className={`"flex flex-col sm:flex-row w-full h-auto justify-between space-x-2 space-y-2" ${isOpen === false && "hidden sm:flex"}`}>
          <li>element 1</li>
          <li>element 2</li>
          <li>element 3</li>
          <li>element 4</li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </header>
  );
}
```

Happy coding :)

Comment: Sorry to say would you tell me please what you get message from my question?

Comment: my responsive design work fine but i want to have smooth appearance of the list items top to down in slow motion when i click the burger button on the nav bar small screen

Comment: Sorry @JsWizard not working. Can you try it on your IDE?

Comment: @UsamaAbdulRazzaq I tried to implement your goal, but didn't with no JS. so I recommended using `Headless UI`, check this link https://headlessui.dev/react/menu#basic-example and you can customise it.