# CSS Transition Only Applying to Entry Animation?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, web

I'm currently trying to use CSS transitions to smooth out the expansion and contraction of divs on hover, however, the Transition property only seems to apply to the entry animation (i.e. mouse hovering, div expands) but not the exit (mouse leaves, div collapses). Is there a separate property/something else I'm missing to make this animation consistent?

```css
.collapsed-content {
  max-height: 3rem;
  transition: max-height 1.75s ease-in;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.collapsed-content :hover {
  max-height: 300rem;
  transition: max-height 1.75s ease-in;
}
```

```html
<div className='collapsed-content'>
  <p> Content </p>
  <div>
    <p> More content to reveal here </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What are you trying to target with `.collapsed-content :hover`?

Answer (score 0):

How about this (based on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16028878/animating-max-height-with-css-transitions))

```css
.collapsed-content {
  overflow: hidden;
  max-height: 3rem;
  transition: max-height 1s cubic-bezier(0, 1, 0, 1);
  background: tomato;
  padding: 0 1rem;
}

.collapsed-content:hover {
  max-height: 300rem;
  transition: max-height 2s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<div class="collapsed-content" >
  <p> Content </p>
  <div>
    <p> More content to reveal here </p>
  </div>
</div>
```