# Multiline container unfolding animation

Tags: html, css

How should CSS multiline container (e.g. content block or alert) unfolding animation should be managed?

http://plnkr.co/edit/Qq5fzeb3GBengviVNimC?p=preview

```
.alert {
  background: turquoise;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;

    opacity: 0;
    max-height: 0;
}

body:hover .alert {
    display: block !important;
    opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transition: 2s;
  -moz-transition: 2s;
  -ms-transition: 2s;
  transition: 2s;
  max-height: 100px;
}
```

The problem here is 'multiline', as you can see, the block height isn't a fixed value.

```
<div class="alert">Alert!<br>Alert!<br>Alert!</div>
```

While `max-height: 100px` is near real block height, it works fine. If `max-height` is smaller, the animation would be jaggy in the end, and `max-height: 9999px` will make the transition too fast.

Can this be done without calculating the exact height in JS?

Comment: As far as I know, CSS height can't be smoothly transitioned without fixed sizes. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6089548/css3-height-transition-not-working for discussion. You don't have to specify the height ahead of time in CSS if you use JS, as that link shows, or as TijnvW demonstrated in their answer.

Answer (score -1):

Calculating the height can be done in jQuery indeed, I did the following to solve your problem:

```js
$("#out").html("Block height: " + $("#alert").height());
//solely for demonstration, you can delete this line

$("#alert").css('height','0px');

$('#alert').mouseover( function(){
    $("#alert").css('height', '58px');
});
$('#alert').mouseout( function(){
    $("#alert").css('height', '0px');
});
```

```css
#alert {
  background: turquoise;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  //max-height: 0; this causes .height() to always display '0' so delete this here, and set this via jQuery

}

body:hover #alert {
 display: block !important;
 opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transition: 2s;
  -moz-transition: 2s;
  -ms-transition: 2s;
  transition: 2s;
 // max-height: 100px !important; set this via jQuery
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Hello!</p>
<div id="alert">Alert!<br>Alert!<br>Alert!</div>
<p>Hello again!</p>

<span id="out"></span>
```

Comment: The OP specified in their question, "Can this be done without calculating the exact height in JS?"

Comment: @Palpatim Yes, it was the second question. I will accept JS answer if it is impossible to do with CSS only. But such solution suffers from hard-coded height, the height could be also changed on zoom, resize or change in block content.

Comment: Ooops, completely overlooked the word 'without', I'm sorry!
Wouldn't know if this could be done in pure CSS, so I'm curious if anyone has an other solution

Comment: Don't think anyone knows a CSS-only solution, though problems with change in block content could be overcome with .change() for form field elements