# How to animate sticky header?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a sticky header which is fixed on scroll using jQuery when reaching a height of 160.

```
$(window).scroll(function()
{

    if( $(window).scrollTop() > 160)
{

        $('.dark-menu').addClass('stickyNav');
        $('header').addClass('mainHeaderFixed');
        $(".menu-second-menu-container").hide();
        $(".menu-first-menu-container").addClass('new-end');
        $("a.main-logo").hide();
        $("a.small-logo").show();
        $(".bp-phone").addClass("stickyNumber");
        $("img.telephoneIconHeader").addClass("stickyImg");
        $("a.topHeaderMailto").addClass("stickyaa");        
}
else
{
        $('.dark-menu').removeClass('stickyNav');
        $("a.topHeaderMailto").removeClass("stickyaa");
        $('header').removeClass('mainHeaderFixed');
        $(".menu-second-menu-container").show();
        $(".menu-first-menu-container").removeClass('new-end');
        $("a.main-logo").show();
        $("a.small-logo").hide();
        $(".bp-phone").removeClass("stickyNumber");
        $("img.telephoneIconHeader").removeClass("stickyImg");
} 
});
```

This is fine for showing / hiding elements, but I want the whole sticky nav and the backbar to animate on scroll.

I have tried to apply CSS on the header sections:

```
    -webkit-transition: height 5s;
    -moz-transition: height 5s;
    transition: height 5s;
```

But this is not working. What can I do to make this animate on scroll?

**Here is my site:**

http://insurancefocus.bemediadev.com.au/

**Here is what I would like to achieve:**

https://codepen.io/malZiiirA/pen/cbfED

Comment: which kind of annimation do you want and in wich compomnent ????

Comment: I would like it to be something like this: https://codepen.io/malZiiirA/pen/cbfED

Comment: we couldn't open the site link you have given, can you give the css of classes you are adding and removing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit**

The header of the pen you posted is always fixed, not sticky. If you want this, you need to give your `.main` `position: fixed` from the start and just change the height of the elements.

The transition has no effect on your header because it does not have a set `height`. It just gets recalculated when you swap out the two logo versions.

For more information on this, see [css3 height transition not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6089548/css3-height-transition-not-working) or if you don't want to specify a `height`, see [How can I transition height: 0; to height: auto; using CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3508605/how-can-i-transition-height-0-to-height-auto-using-css)

**Old**

Setting a transition on height will only show effect if the height of the element actually changes. In your case, the height remains the same. Try using the following CSS to change the `height` of your element and you will see the transition.

```
.main {
    height: 100px;

    -webkit-transition: height 5s;
    -moz-transition: height 5s;
    transition: height 5s;
}

.main.mainHeaderFixed {
    height: 160px;
}
```

Comment: I have added the height on this and it still doesn't work well. Thanks for your help!

Comment: that's because the header in the pen is fixed all the time and just shrinks after a certain scroll distance. I will update the answer.

Comment: Hi Tom, thank you for your valuable answers. I am going to do more testing out today and will update soon. Thanks again :)

Comment: you are welcome. Just ask if you have any questions.